# Passing a parameter to a dstat plugin

Tags: python, monitoring, programming

I wrote a simple plugin (`dstat_externalBackup.py`) for `dstat` to monitor the filesystem free space and placed it in `/usr/share/dstat` and it works as intended.

```
€ dstat --externalBackup 3600
extern
 free 
 226G 
 226G
```

The code is below. As you may notice, the filesystem being monitored is hard coded in the plugin which is suboptimal. Has anyone figured out how to pass a parameter to the plugin so I can enter the filesystem to monitor on the command line?

```
### Author: J. Hendrix / Dag Wieers    

class dstat_plugin(dstat):
    '''
    Provides a test playground to test syntax and structure.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'externalBackup'
        self.nick = ( 'free' , )
        self.vars = ( 'text' , )
        self.type = 's'
        self.width = 6
        self.scale = 0

    def extract(self):
        import subprocess
        import re
        temp1 = subprocess.check_output( ["/bin/df" , "-h" , "--output=avail", "/media/jhendrix/externalBackup" ] ) 
        temp2 = re.search( '\n([^\n]+)\n' , temp1 )
        self.val['text'] = temp2.group( 1 )
```